# Android JSONObject decimal not displaying

Tags: android, json, android-listview

I'm having some trouble getting one of my JSONObjects to display in a ListView. I'm using the standard JSON Parser, Async Task etc., and all works fine for everything except one particular string, which is the total. Here's my code snippets:

JSON:

```
{
       "item": "Item name",
       "quantity": "67",
       "unit": "m",
       "total": "603.00"
 },
```

Android:

```
if (jsonStr != null) {
try {
    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

    items = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_ITEMS);

    for (int a = 0; a < items.length(); a++) {
        JSONObject l = items.getJSONObject(a);

        String item = l.getString(TAG_ITEM_NAME);
        String unit = l.getString(TAG_UNIT);
        String total = l.getString(TAG_TOTAL);
        String quantity = l.getString(TAG_QUANTITY);

        Log.d("item got: ", "> " + item);
        Log.d("unit got: ", "> " + unit);
        Log.d("total got: ", "> " + total);
        Log.d("qty got: ", "> " + quantity);

        HashMap<String, String> myItems = new HashMap<String, String>();

        myItems.put(TAG_ITEM_NAME, item);
        myItems.put(TAG_UNIT, unit);
        myItems.put(TAG_TOTAL, total);
        myItems.put(TAG_QUANTITY, quantity);

        itemList.add(myItems);
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    } else {
            Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
    }

return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        // Dismiss the progress dialog
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
        /**
         * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
         * */
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(ItemsActivity.this,
                itemList, R.layout.item_list_item,
                new String[] { TAG_ITEM_NAME, TAG_UNIT, TAG_TOTAL, TAG_QUANTITY }, 
                new int[] { R.id.itemName, R.id.unit, R.id.total, R.id.quantity});

        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

XML:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/itemName"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/total"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/unit"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/quantity"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Now, according to the Log, all four are 'got', but when I try and put them into my ListView, the total (a decimal figure) will not display. Single numbers and other non-decimal numbers display perfectly, and everything is a string in the JSON, so why can't I display my total?

Confused...

Comment: Can you include how you are displaying your values? I smell a typo.

Comment: @Marius - I'm an idiot! The code I posted wasn't the actual code, but you were in the right area. One of the XML TextViews didn't match the R.id.total, so after a quick change, it displays perfectly. Thanks for steering me in the right direction!!

Comment: I suggest next time you override `getView` method of your adapter, so you have more control over what happens to your textViews, also some spellchecking - findViewById(someWrongId).someMethod(); -> NPE. Also, if I recall correctly, you can `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` to avoid re-creating adapter.

Comment: Thanks Marius. I guess I just got so close to the code I didn't see the issue.

Answer (score -1):

use this ,

```
findViewById(R.id.itemName).setText(myItems.get(TAG_ITEM_NAME));
```

but before that make , myItems accessible.

Comment: He's not overriding `getView`, your answer is completely irrelevant.

Comment: are you correct , he can use that by using Activity context.

Comment: I'm pretty much sure I'm correct: 
`ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(ItemsActivity.this,
                itemList, R.layout.item_list_item,
                new String[] { TAG_ITEM_NAME, TAG_UNIT, TAG_TOTAL, TAG_QUANTITY }, 
                new int[] { R.id.itemName, R.id.unit, R.id.total, R.id.quantity});

        setListAdapter(adapter);`

Comment: Yes, I have findViewById(...) elsewhere in the code - I only posted the bit that was causing the problem. It's fixed now :)